# Comparison between join+groupBy and unionAll+groupBy in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I dont know whether this question has been asked before or not. But I am having a problem with join followed by `groupBy` on data which is causing memory exceed in Spark and process failure.

I have devised strategy and compared for two `DataFrame`s with `join` + `groupBy` and `unionAll` + `groupBy` ( obviously code is larger since making two of same schema and aligning those for able to union them properly) observed same result.

My problem I dont have enough experience with this stuff and dont know exact comparison for memory and heap space consumption for those two?
can anyone help me pls?

1. heap space consumption comparison
2. Memory consumption
3. any other comparison if you want to state and feel is important in order to increase efficiency

Comment: Unfortunately this is too broad to answer even if groupBy problems have been already asked on the site several times. To find those QAs, Google is your friend. Nevertheless, besides suffering from behind broad, your question also falls in the category of why my code isn't working and missing a minimum reproducible and complete example. So please review your question because it's subject of being closed.

Comment: Can you focus on _"But I am having a problem with join followed by groupBy on data which is causing memory exceed in Spark and process failure._" What problems do you face? Does the code fail? Because of memory? What's the final result?

Comment: yes code fails for Heap Space error. and I unit tested and found that it is failing because of join